# Add DROP USER statements before each CREATE USER

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an input file:

```
CREATE USER A
CREATE USER B
CREATE USER FOO IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
```

I want to add DROP USER statements like so:

```
DROP USER A
CREATE USER A
DROP USER B
CREATE USER B
DROP USER FOO
CREATE USER FOO IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
```

How can I do that? I tried sed but failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to add a `DROP USER x` line before the `CREATE USER x` line, this could be an option:

```
sed -E 's/^CREATE USER ([^[:space:]]+)/DROP USER \1\nCREATE USER \1/g'
```

The matching part

```
-E             use extended regular expressions in the script

^              match from the beginning of the line
CREATE USER    literal match
( )            ( and ) captures what matches between them and puts in references numbered
               \1 for first capture, \2 for second, up to \9
[^[:space:]]+  [[: something :]] means a character class, like :space: for whitespace
               characters.
               ^ means NOT, so we don't want whitespaces in the username
               + means match 1 or more non-whitespace characters
```

So `CREATE USER A` puts `A` in `\1`

The replacement part:

```
DROP USER \1    literal DROP USER and whatever \1 references - that is A in the example
\n              a newline
CREATE USER \1  literal CREATE USER and again whatever \1 references
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -E 's/^CREATE( USER \S+)/DROP\1\n&/' file`?

Comment: @potong `-E 's/^CREATE( USER [^[:space:]]+)/DROP\1\n&/'` to make it Posix compliant would work. It's nice and shorter than my version. -  or `[^\s]+` instead of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  g/^CREATE USER/t.-1\
  s/^CREATE/DROP/\
  s/\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) .*/\1 \2 \3/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

Using an `ed` script named `script.ed`

```
g/^CREATE USER/t.-1\
s/^CREATE/DROP/\
s/\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\) .*/\1 \2 \3/
,p
Q
```

Then

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

Change the `Q` to `w` if in-place editing of *file.txt* is desired.